# What methodOverride mean in node-express-mongoose-demo repository?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've looked at the following code:

```
  app.use(methodOverride(function (req, res) {
    if (req.body && typeof req.body === 'object' && '_method' in req.body) {
      // look in urlencoded POST bodies and delete it
      var method = req.body._method;
      delete req.body._method;
      return method;
    }
  }));
```

in [node-express-mongoose-demo](https://github.com/madhums/node-express-mongoose-demo/blob/master/config/express.js#L82) repository and just interested what do the do? Does anybody could please explain me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the official documentation :

[Method Override](https://github.com/expressjs/method-override) lets you use PUT and DELETE http methods. In this case, your app looks for a _method parameter to a POST query, and if it finds it, overrides the POST request for a 'delete', and removes the parameter from the body. In practice, you'd use it like this on the client :

```
<form method="POST" action="/resource" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
  <button type="submit">Delete resource</button>
</form>
```

Note the hidden input _method that will trigger your middleware's function.

Step by step :

```
if (req.body && typeof req.body === 'object' && '_method' in req.body) { //If we have a body, and it contains a _method field

  var method = req.body._method; // Override the POST method with the value of the _method field (eg:DELETE in our example)
  delete req.body._method; //remove the field from the body, we don't need it anymore
  return method;
} //And our POST request is now a DELETE!
```